# Integrating sensor data into IFC file for visualization of BIM model in bimvie.ws

Tags: javascript, sensors, ifc, bim

Currently using bimvie.ws to visualize an IFC file with javascript. Now we would like to add sensor (dummy) data, for let's say temperature, in order to improve functionality of the visualization.

However, we are not sure on how we can do that yet?
We were able to define spaces within the IFC file of a building, now we would like to be able to show colour ramps of temperature change within the individual spaces.
With the goal to develop and design smart building (monitoring) systems.

It should fit in the following lines of code:

```
{
  "type": {
    "name": "IfcSpace",
    "includeAllSubTypes": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some documentation on sensor integration [here](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/sensor-integration/td-p/8667958).

Also two (out of many) articles seem to describe a relevant method:

- [Expansion of IFC model with structural sensors](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/308164615_Expansion_of_IFC_model_with_structural_sensors)
- [A framework for integrating BIM and IoT through open standards](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0926580517305964)